# How can I show a heading element on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using keyframes but my `h1` is not visible on button click. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```js
function abc() {
  document.querySelector('.h1cls').classList.add('fadeIn')
}
```

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 150ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 5000ms;
  /*opacity:1;*/
}

.one .two .h1cls {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <h1 class="h1cls">hello</h1>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="abc()">asd</button>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-lamport-12kgz?file=/index.html:0-994

actually I am using opacity . I am setting opacity to 1 after button click.

Comment: You have a typo: you forgot to close on of your `div` tags

Answer (score 0):

In your `abc()` function, you should also remove `h1cls` class due to the fact that it still applies `opacity: 0` style.

```
 function abc(){
    document.querySelector('.h1cls').classList.add('fadeIn')
    document.querySelector('.h1cls').classList.remove('h1cls')
 }
```

Comment: My solution differs from original code snippet only in this function, so I didnt find it worth of duplicating it.

Comment: It's worth it to show that it actually solves the problem. Many answers are posted on this site that don't. It's a matter of one button click, so why not?

Answer (score 0):

It is animating but then disappearing immediately. You need to tell the system to keep the final state of the animation. You do this with animation-fill-mode: forwards

Note that the animation will only run on the first click of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `animation-fill-mode:forwards;` property too in the fadeClass in order to make this work

```js
function abc() {
  document.querySelector('.h1cls').classList.add('fadeIn')
}
```

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 150ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  /*animation-delay: 5000ms;*/
  animation-fill-mode:forwards; // add this line
  /*opacity:1;*/
}

.one .two .h1cls {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">

    <h1 class="h1cls">hello</h1>
    <div></div>

    <button onclick="abc()">asd</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed **animation-fill-mode** property in **fadeIn** CSS class.

Correct code:

```css
.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 150ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 5000ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Answer (score 0):

you can used the toggle class and transition

```js
function abc() {
  document.querySelector('.h1cls').classList.toggle('fadeIn')
}
```

```css
.one .two .h1cls {
transition: opacity 150ms linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

.one .two .h1cls.fadeIn {

  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">

    <h1 class="h1cls">hello</h1>
    <div></div>

    <button onclick="abc()">asd</button>
    
    </div>
    </div>
```

or with animation

```js
function abc() {
  document.querySelector('.h1cls').classList.toggle('fadeIn')
}
```

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}



.one .two .h1cls {
  opacity: 0;
}

.one .two .h1cls.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 150ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">

    <h1 class="h1cls">hello</h1>
    <div></div>

    <button onclick="abc()">asd</button>
    
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

When we click on button it just adding class `fadeIn` and this class will animate from opacity 0 to opacity 1. But after animation completed it will again hide, so add `opacity:1!important` in .fadeIn class property.

In simple way just add `opacity:1!important` in `fadeIn` css property.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
       @keyframes fadeIn {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            to {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
      .fadeIn {
            animation-name: fadeIn;
            animation-duration: 150ms;
            animation-timing-function: linear;
            animation-delay: 5000ms;
            opacity:1 !important;
        }

        .one .two .h1cls {
          opacity: 0;
        }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="one">
        <div class="two">
        <h1 class="h1cls">hello</h1>
      <div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="abc()">asd</button>
    <script>
    function abc(){
      document.querySelector('.h1cls').classList.add('fadeIn')
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered *low-quality*. Without explaination it is hard to understand what you did or how you would solve the issue. As such it is hard to reproduce and has a questionable value as "help".

Comment: Maybe they can understand by themself by looking difference between code of question and answer.

Comment: You miss the crucial point. Solving an issue for someone does not help the person to fix the issue in feature or to understand how you solved it. A solution that the OP has no diea how to apply will be useless to him.